# div not floating to the right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have looked through as many of the questions asking the same thing and as far as I can tell none of them apply to my situation. Of course, I'm a newb and could have just missed connections. Anyway, I have a simple webpage that I am designing for a custom tab on Facebook. The link (that goes to advertisements) that I have on the bottom of the right side has floated correctly to the right side. But the block of images and the header at the top will not go right. I'll include the snippets of my code that apply to these elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C00000;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
td {
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
div.content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 730px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
div.brands {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
div#providers {
  float: right;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#ads {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a#ads:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: B22222;
}
#ads:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom:1em;">Our Services</h1>
  <div class="brands">
    <h3>Our Best Brands</h3>
    <a href="http://www.stihlusa.com/" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.stihlusa.com/content/images/layout/stihl_print_logo.gif" alt="stihl logo" height="24%" width="24%" style="padding-right:15px;" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.acehardware.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=21503026" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Craftsman_logo.svg/215px-Craftsman_logo.svg.png" alt="craftsman logo" />
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://www.acehardware.com/search/index.jsp?kw=AMY+HOWARD+AT+HOME" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.granbyace.com/images/featured/featured-brands/Amy-Howard-logo-642x335.png" alt="amy howard logo" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px;" height="25%" width="25%" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.acehardware.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=35612726" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.acehardware.com/cms_widgets/22/78/2278272_assets/brand_07_valspar.png" alt="valspar logo" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <h3>Full Service Paint Center</h3>
  <p style="width:40%">At our paint center, we can make any color from our color chips. Or if you need something special, we can custom match colors for a perfect fit. We offer Valspar Optimus, Valspar Aspire, Clark+Kensington, and Royal paint.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in order to float small container divs to a direction they need a fixed width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're targeting the Div and telling it to float right - as the div has no defined width (and as such is setting its self to max width), there's nowhere for it to float.

You can either set a width then float the entire div, or just use text-align: right; to push the elements within the div to the right.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try that. I have been scratching my head for the last 2 hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. And that solved the problem!

Comment: Try not to think too much into it, 90% of any developers job is googling sh*t they already knew, code is a mind f*ck :P

Comment: So true! Thanks again!